# Remove space within a string when using file name and current date

Tags: r

I want to export data to a file with a certain name. Finally, just a name with the current date. So far I have:

```
string<- 'name'
time <- Sys.Date()

file_name<- paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d"), "csv", sep = ".")
file_name<- cat(string,file_name)
```

And the output is:

```
> string<- 'name'
> time <- Sys.Date()
> file_name<- paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d"), "csv", sep = ".")
> file_name<- cat(string,file_name)
name 2018-12-04.csv
```

I only need to remove the space between "name" and "2018-12-04.csv" but I don't see how respectively why it is there.

Comment: Just use paste0 instead of paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste0`

```
paste0(string, file_name)
#[1] "name2018-12-04.csv"
```

or `cat` with `sep = ""`

```
cat(string,file_name, sep = "")
#name2018-12-04.csv
```

`cat` has default `sep` argument as space (`" "`), you need to override it.

and same is the case with `paste`

```
paste(string, file_name, sep = "")
```

Comment: Thank you! I also found > cat(sprintf("Fitted_APDs_%s", time)) right now :)